# Expressjs call middleware from another middle ware

Tags: express

**routes.js**

```
var router = require('express').Router();
router.get('/all', require('./all'));
module.exports = router;
```

**all.js  work**

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
   res.send('this one work');
};
```

**all.js not work**.

```
const start = function(req, res, next) {
  res.write('start');
  next();
}
const finish = function(req, res, next){
  res.write('finish!');
  res.end();
}

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
   start,
   finish
};
```

How to make the all.js to work.
Update: complete code of the page

Comment: You should add the total code of pages

Comment: update more code

Comment: @pzaenger I know what way but I want my routes file to be clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your routes.js to something like this:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var all = require('./all');
// Call your middlewares in the desired order 
router.get('/all', all.start, all.finish);
module.exports = router;
```

Read also this [question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31928417/chaining-multiple-pieces-of-middleware-for-specific-route-in-expressjs) to get some more details.

**According to your comment:**

*all.js*:

```
const start = function(req, res, next) {
  res.write('start');
  next();
}

const finish = function(req, res, next){
  res.write('finish!');
  res.end();
}

module.exports = [start, finish];
```

*routes.js*:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
router.get('/all', require('./all'));
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Let me know, if I can still improve my answer :) Since you haven't upvoted or accepted answers to any of your questions, please read also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will work for you

You have to change only two places in your code otherwise, all the things are right.

**routes.js**

```
    var router = require('express').Router();
    var all = require('./all');
    //call both start and finish from all.js file here
    router.get('/all', all.start, all.finish);
    module.exports = router;
```

**all.js**

```
    const start = function (req, res, next) {
        res.write('start');
        next();
    }
    const finish = function (req, res, next) {
        res.write('finish!');
        res.end();
    }

   //export in this way 
    module.exports = {
        start,
        finish
    }
```