# Function between route and route handler is not executing as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to write API's of which some of them has role based authorization. Further I am using JWT for authentication for my API's.

Below is the code, I am trying to write. However, when I hit "/user/:email" endpoint, authorize function is not getting called. Always, *getUser* function is getting called. I was in an assumption that at first authorize function should be called followed by *getUser*.

Can someone enlighten me why *authorize* function is not getting called when I hit "/user/:email" endpoint? What wrong am I doing here? And how can I correctly handle this scenario?

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router();
var expressJwt = require('express-jwt');

var authorize = function(role){     
  expressJwt({secret:'secretKey'}, (req, res, next) =>{
    console.log('req.role is', req.role);
    if(req.role === role){
       next();
    }else{
       res.status(403).send({message: 'Unauthorized'});
    }
  })  
}

var getUser = function(req,res,next){
    res.status(200).send("Hello user");
}

router.get('/user/:email', authorize('Admin'), getUser);
```

Comment: I would say your middleware just returns some functions inside an array. These brackers are strange

Comment: @Rashomon: If I remove square brackets inside authorize function, I am getting a compiler/interpreter error as "Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]".

Answer (score 1):

`authorize` is called when the application starts up, not when you hit "/user/:email". Calling `authorize('Admin')` just returns undefined which will not cause the `console.log` being executed, neither when "/user/:email" is hit.

I think what you want to achieve is applying multiple callbacks sequentially to one route.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31928417/chaining-multiple-pieces-of-middleware-for-specific-route-in-expressjs)

So, `authorize('Admin')` should return a middleware (also called callback), such as:

```
return expressJwt({secret:'secretKey'}, (req, res, next) =>{...})
```

Comment: To some extent you are correct, I have to apply multiple callback sequentially to one route. But how can I achieve this? How can I pass "Admin" role into the callback function authorize?

Comment: @Sreehari - sorry what's the point of passing role from request to authentication method? Shouldn't role be read from the authenticated user? in which case you would handle authorization after you fetch the user

Comment: @Milan: I have roles like 'Admin', 'customer', 'partner'. Authentication simply authenticates all kinds of users and generates JWT token. Now, some of the routes are accessible only to 'Admin'. So I need to authorize user before route Handler is executed. How can I do it then?

Comment: @Sreehari - well if you want to check if user of the certain JWT token has certain permission, you can try using `express-jwt-permissions` package in conjunction with `express-jwt`.

Comment: @Milan: Thanks Milan. express-jwt-permissions seems to a good one. I will try this.