# How to combine two middleware and export as one?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I have a utility file which basically has two functions (one to detect user location and another to get user device details) acting as middlewares. Now I would like to know whether it is possible to combine both the middlewares together as one so that it could be used with other middlewares on the route. I would also like to have the freedom of using the functions in the utility file individually when required.

**Utility file**

```
const axios             = require("axios");
const requestIp         = require("request-ip");

const getDeviceLocation = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        // ToDO: Check if it works on production
        const clientIp  = requestIp.getClientIp(req);
        const ipToCheck = clientIp === "::1" || "127.0.0.1" ? "" : clientIp;

        const details = await axios.get("https://geoip-db.com/json/" + ipToCheck);

        // Attach returned results to the request body
        req.body.country    = details.data.country_name;
        req.body.state      = details.data.state;
        req.body.city       = details.data.city;

        // Run next middleware
        next();
    }
    catch(error) {
        return res.status(500).json({ message: "ERROR_OCCURRED" });
    }
};

const getDeviceClient = async (req, res, next) => {
    const userAgent = req.headers["user-agent"];

    console.log("Device UA: " + userAgent);
    next();
};

module.exports = { getDeviceLocation, getDeviceClient };
```

**Example Routes**

```
app.post("/v1/register", [getDeviceLocation, getDeviceClient, Otp.verify], User.create);

app.post("/v1/auth/google", [getDeviceLocation, getDeviceClient, Auth.verifyGoogleIdToken], Auth.useGoogle);
```

I would like to have `getDeviceLocation` and `getDeviceClient` combined into one say `getDeviceInfo` yet have the freedom to use `getDeviceLocation` and `getDeviceClient` individually when required on any route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case maybe you can use something simple like this

```
const getDeviceInfo = async (req, res, next) => {
    await getDeviceClient(req, res, async () => {
        await getDeviceLocation(req, res, next)
    })
}
```

But you may need to handle error cases.

Comment: In that case I won't be able to use the individual functions independently, I guess.

Comment: no you can still use them! you just create this as another function/middleware.

Comment: Can it be used with await ?

Comment: what do you mean?!

Comment: I meant can it be done like `await getDeviceClient(req, res, next); await getDeviceLocation(req, res, next);`

Comment: not if you want to use the individual functions independently

Comment: Actually my IDE says `Promise returned is ignored`, so I thought of asking.

Comment: ah that's why I told you `But you may need to handle error cases.`, but anyway to remove that error just add await before each call, I'll update the answer

Comment: I guess you are missing a async statement on the first await function.

Comment: :) Looks like that's what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Express allows you to [declare middleware in an array](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html), so you can simply define an array of the middlewares you'd like to combine:

```
const getDeviceLocation = async (req, res, next) => {
...
};

const getDeviceClient = async (req, res, next) => {
...
};

const getDeviceInfo = [getDeviceLocation, getDeviceClient];

module.exports = { getDeviceLocation, getDeviceClient, getDeviceInfo };
```

You can then use any combination of one or both of the middleware wherever you like:

```
app.use('/foo', getDeviceLocation, () => {});
app.use('/bar', getDeviceClient, () => {});
app.use('/baz', getDeviceInfo, () => {});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to avoid callback hells you can use something like this:

```
const nextInterceptor = error => {
  if (error) { throw error; }
};

const combineMiddlewares = middlewares => (req, res, next) => (
  middlewares.reduce((previousMiddleware, currentMiddleware) => (
    previousMiddleware.then(() => currentMiddleware(req, res, nextInterceptor))
  ), Promise.resolve())
    .then(() => next())
    .catch(next)
);

const commonMiddlewares = combineMiddlewares([getDeviceLocation, getDeviceClient]);

app.post("/v1/register", [commonMiddlewares, Otp.verify], User.create);
app.post("/v1/auth/google", [commonMiddlewares, Auth.verifyGoogleIdToken], Auth.useGoogle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using connect nodemodule you can do combine the middle ware and expose a new end point for it. Ref here a sample code https://blog.budiharso.info/2015/07/28/Combine-multiple-express-middleware/

Comment: Yes, I have gone through it before asking here but it asks for connect package. Is there any other alternative way of doing?

Comment: In the code which you posted you are following the chaining multiple middle ware calls without using any third party module Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31928417/chaining-multiple-pieces-of-middleware-for-specific-route-in-expressjs

Comment: If you still want to expose a different route, then using node modules 3rd party like combine, compose-middleware, middleware-flow are the other options.

Comment: Which one do you suppose is better. I haven't used any of them.

Comment: combine is better

Answer (score 0):

It's simple and doesn't require to install anything. Just use:

```js
const {Router} = require('express')

const combinedMiddleware = Router().use([middleware1, middleware2, middleware3])
```

Now you can use combined middleware where necessary. For example:

```js
app.get('/some-route', (req, res, next) => {
  req.query.someParam === 'someValue'
    ? combinedMiddleware1(req, res, next)
    : combinedMiddleware2(req, res, next)
})
```