# block user ip in node js middleware

Tags: node.js, middleware, express-rate-limit

i want to use express-rate-limiter in a middleware of my node.js app. how can i?
in a usuall app, it's in the server.js but i want to blcok user in a middleware.

thanks for your responses

```js
const express=require('express');
const app=express();
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');
// limit user logins
const tokenLimiter = rateLimit({
    windowMs: 3 * 60 * 1000,
    max: 3,
    statusCode: 200,
    message: {
        status: 429,
        error: 'block msg'
    },
    handler: function (req, res) {
        res.status(429).json({ msg: 'block msg' });
    },
});

module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    let token = req.cookies.authorization;
    if (!token) {
        token = req.headers.authorization;
    }
    if (!token) return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'please login' });
    try {
        const verified = jwt.verify(token, process.env.THE_TOKEN_SECRET);
        req.user = verified;
        next();
    } catch (e) {
        app.use(tokenLimiter);
        res.status(200).json({ router: "login" });
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't think you can conditionally `app.use` like that inside one middleware; it'll just be added to the end, and multiple times (remember it has app scope).  Instead, define a `skip` function in express-rate-limit's options that checks if `req.user` is defined, and add the rate limiter right after the authentication middleware.

Comment: You could adapt [this example](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki/Overall-example#minimal-protection-against-password-brute-force) with `rate-limiter-flexible` package.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be doing this, this voilates the idea of rate limitter.
Express executes middlewares sequentially.You should be calling your middleware right after the rate limiter in server.js. I would use something like below in my server.js

```
const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit')
const limiter = rateLimit({
windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
max: 100, // Limit each IP to 100 requests per `window` (here, per 15 minutes)
standardHeaders: true, // Return rate limit info in the `RateLimit-*` headers
legacyHeaders: false, // Disable the `X-RateLimit-*` headers
}) // Apply the rate limiting middleware to all requests
app.use(limiter)
app.use(secondMiddleware)
```

Or you could also chain them like [Chaining multiple pieces of middleware for specific route in ExpressJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31928417/chaining-multiple-pieces-of-middleware-for-specific-route-in-expressjs)

*But if you really want to do it, one workaround is in your code on catch you are redirecting to login, you can add the rate limitter just at login as a middleware.*

Answer (score 0):

express-rate-limit has a `skipSuccessfulRequests` option to only¹ count requests that result in an error. By default it looks at the status code, but you can customize it to look at other aspects via a custom `requestWasSuccessful` function:

```js
const express=require('express');
const app=express();
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');
// limit failed logins
const tokenLimiter = rateLimit({
    windowMs: 3 * 60 * 1000,
    max: 3,
    statusCode: 200,
    message: {
        status: 429,
        error: 'block msg'
    },
    // note: a custom handler function will override the above statusCode and message settings
    // handler: function (req, res) {
    //     res.status(429).json({ msg: 'block msg' });
    // }, 
    skipSuccessfulRequests: true,
    requestWasSuccessful: function (req, res) {
      return !req.tokenVerificationFailed;
    },
});

function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
    let token = req.cookies.authorization;
    if (!token) {
        token = req.headers.authorization;
    }
    if (!token) return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'please login' });
    try {
        const verified = jwt.verify(token, process.env.THE_TOKEN_SECRET);
        req.user = verified;
        next();
    } catch (e) {
        res.tokenVerificationFailed = true;
        res.status(200).json({ router: "login" });
    }
};

app.use(tokenLimiter);
app.use(verifyToken);
```

(I also commented out your custom `handler` function since it would conflict with the `statusCode` and `message` configuration options.)

¹ Technically it counts all requests and then un-counts the successful ones, so a million requests at once would probably still be limited, even if they would ultimately all be successful otherwise.

---

For an alternative option, you could run `verifyToken` first, and then configure `express-rate-limit` with a custom `skip` function that skips any request with a `req.user` field. This would avoid the 'million requests at once' issue, but it would apply the limiter to unauthenticated users who just don't have any token, which doesn't appear to be your intention.

---

Disclosure: I'm the author of express-rate-limit.