# What is the definition of express app.post's multiple parameters in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

I meet a problem when tracing the node.js express application. Following is the sample
people often using:

```
app.get('/api/users', function(req, res) {
    const user_id = req.query.id;
    const token = req.query.token;
    const geo = req.query.geo;

    res.send({
        'user_id': user_id,
        'token': token,
        'geo': geo
    });
});
```

However, in the csurf case, the authentication function is this:

```
app.post('/process', parseForm, csrfProtection, function(req, res) {
    res.send('data is being processed')
})
```

The problem is what the definition of express app function parameters like get or post,
it seems very different from the usually usage scenario like the first case above,
and the office document in express doesn't explain the four parameters situation.
Any instruction is highly appreciated, thanks a lot.

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.post.method and https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#middleware-callback-function-examples

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chaining multiple pieces of middleware for specific route in ExpressJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31928417/chaining-multiple-pieces-of-middleware-for-specific-route-in-expressjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parseForm`, `csrfProtection` and your `function(req,res)` are all request handlers/middleware and you can have as many as you need (minimum 1), passed one after another as arguments to `app.get()`, `app.post()` or any `app.xxx()` verb.

They are called on after the other and they advance to the next one, when the previous one calls `next()`.  They are all passed the arguments `(req, res, next)`.  This is how a middleware chain works.

So, in this specific handler:

```
app.post('/process', parseForm, csrfProtection, function(req, res) {
    res.send('data is being processed')
});
```

It will first call `parseForm(req, res, next)` and when/if that calls `next()`, it will then call `csrfProtection(req, res, next)` and when/if that calls `next()`, it will then call your `function(req, res)`.  FYI, next is actually passed to that too, you just don't have to declare it if you're not going to use it.

Whichever one of these wants to end the response sends a response with something like `res.send()` and then does not call `next()` and the response will be done and the chain will end.  This can be done from anywhere in the chain.

---

You will see in the [Express doc](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.post.method) that it shows:

```
app.post(path, callback [, callback ...])
```

That notation indicates that you can have one or more callbacks passed after the path.  `parseForm`, `csrfProtection` and `function(req, res)` are all callbacks that matches this calling signature.