# The Express.js interface is not functioning correctly

Tags: typescript, express, go-gin

Express.js use questions:

#### Code:

```js
app.use(A)
app.use(B)


{
    const isCurlR = app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        next()
    })
    isCurlR.get('/getLatest', (req, res) => {})
}

{
    const isNotCurlR = app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        next()
    })
    isNotCurlR.get('/getLogs', (req, res) => {})
    isNotCurlR.get('/getCard', (req, res) => {})
}
```

#### Router work:

A → B → isCurlR → isNotCurlR → /getLatest

A → B → isCurlR → /getLogs

I need: A → B → isNotCurlR → /getLatest

[image]

When I need to access /cli, I can use the isCurlR method correctly,

But when I visit /web, I will first call the isCurlR method,

But he should use isNotCurlR method directly

I don’t want to make the interface path more complicated. At least so far, I am using the golang gin library to achieve this effect.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want forwat thought "isNotCurlR"?

I think it be like below:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('A');
  next();
});
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('B');
  next();
});

{
  const isNotCurlR = app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('isNotCurlR');
    next();
  });
  isCurlR.get('/getLatest', (req, res) => {
    res.send('ok');
  });
}
```

---

*Edit*

I hope you can explain your problem more clearly.
Additionally, using the Express class creates a lot of limitations.
I suggest you check out [*Router*](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router).

Example below:

```
    //Protected
    let admin = express.Router()
    api.use("/admin", admin)
    admin.use((req, res, next) => {
        //Authentication
        try {
            const auth = req.headers.authorization
            if (!auth.includes("Bearer ")) {
                Index.unauthorized(res)
                return
            }
            const token = auth.split(" ")[1]
            req.token = jwt.verify(token, Index.Setting.SecretKey)
            next()
        }
        catch (e) {
            Index.unauthorized(res)
            return
        }
    })

    admin.get("/test", (req, res) => {
        res.json({ role: req.token.role })
    })
```

The routing will look like this: /api/admin/test.
Any route that wants to go through the admin must go through "Authentication" processing.

Comment: The actual work effect, I think it may be a pointer problem, 'IsCurlR' 'isNotCurlR' is not treated differently, because the actual route will run isCurlR before it is accessed.
A -> B -> isCurlR -> /getLogs
A -> B -> isCurlR -> isNotCurlR -> /getLatest

Comment: Because of the limitation of comments, I have added more in the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by *"forwat thought"*? *[format](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/format#Noun) [through](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/through#Preposition)*? Or something else?

Comment: Related: *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)*.

Comment: When I need to access /cli, I can use the isCurlR method correctly,

But when I visit /web, I will first call the isCurlR method,

But he should use isNotCurlR method directly

Comment: This may be what you need: [Chaining multiple pieces of middleware for specific route in ExpressJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31928417/chaining-multiple-pieces-of-middleware-for-specific-route-in-expressjs).

Refer to my code [Express Middleware](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bkkm5t?description=&file=index.js&title=Express%20Starter)